# CSS 100% height for document not viewpoint

Tags: css

I'm having trouble expanding a div to 100% of the doc height (rather than viewpoint height). I have a specific example which is causing issues.

An example can be found here, (jsfiddle's view window didnt allow me to demonstrate the problem correctly, sorry):

http://lavenderstone.co.uk/stackoverflow/

You will notice that if you reduce the viewpoint height below the content height (when scroll bars appear) that the left sidebar and content div's no longer expand to full doc height - they are only displaying the height of the viewpoint.

[image]

I'm new to responsive design using %, so please forgive me. I asked a similar question recently, but the proposes solution did not work for my progressed problem and I felt that a new thread would be more relevant than diverting the topic. Thank you.

Comment: Which browser are you using? It looks fine in Chrome under Mac. When I look in the source I don't see what's called `DOCTYPE` which is probably the reason that Internet Explorer and possibly other browsers are not behaving as expected.

Comment: It's been tested in chrome and firefox under windows 7, but I can also confirm the same issues are present in IE 9 and safari on win7. My solution was found thanks to JrnDel below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a fixed height somewhere, so the height attribute doesn't know how height 100% exactly is. So instead its using your viewport height.

You can fix your problem with the following CSS.

```
#pagewrap {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Using display: table; will cause your height:100%; to be as high as your viewport, or as high as your content if your viewport is to small.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been add this for days now. I think the display table is what I have missed all along, and that has done the trick :) thank you again!

Comment: @kirgy Don't forget to accept answer if it resolved your problem.